# Installation of joomla 3.0 is not being finished

Tags: joomla3.0

I was trying to work on joomla 3.0. I have done everything that is necessary. But the page given in the image is being shown for a long time. Database tables are being created. But it is not going to the next step. Can anyone help me out? TIA[image]

Comment: did you check what happened in your db after running the wizard? did it create any table? or none of them?

Comment: Yes, tables are being created. Not sure all the tables are being created or not.

Comment: did you chose mysqli or mysql?

Comment: I chose mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

With the almost none information you provide I could tell you this.

1. Be sure you are selecting mysql and not mysqli and that the username has all the permissions granted on the database you provided.
2. In your server's home directory, (which is the lowest directory for shared hosting users,) make a new file called "phprc" inside of the .php folder. If the folder doesn't exist yet, create it. The period in front of the folder name means that it's invisible, so make sure you can see invisible files in your FTP client, or use the command "ls -a" to see all files in the command line.
3. Add the following lines to the 'phprc' file:
   Code:
   max_execution_time = 3000 ;
   memory_limit=128M ;
   Then save it.

normally if it is a shared host could take some minutes to reflect the change...but try again after 5 or 10 minutes and you might see it works.